# Is it possible to create a shapekey in Blender which has in-between targets, like in Maya?

Tags: blender, maya

I have been exploring Maya's blendshapes for the past weeks, and it has one very interesting feature called in-between targets. It basically allows one blendshape to include intermediate states between the two basic targets (modified and original objects). I created a couple and tried to export in FBX to use them in Blender, and I get an error message.[image: Blender error when importing the FBX with the blendshapes using the in-between feature] This error does not occur when I import a FBX file without in-between targets in the blendshapes. Also, I wasn't able to find a pure Blender solution to create Shapekeys with in-between targets, which got me wondering if it is even possible.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blender only provides support for one vector per vertex per shapekey so the in-between targets will not be able to be imported directly. I would suggest you [report this as a bug](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/edit/form/1/), while I don't expect in-between shapekeys to be added any time soon, the fbx importer should be fixed to not break on these files.

One thing you could to try is to see if you can export the shapekeys to an mdd or pc2 file. Blender has a [mesh cache modifier](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/modify/mesh_cache.html) that can be used for these files. From 2.78 a new option to try is exporting to an alembic archive [as outlined here](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.78/Alembic)

While blender doesn't support in-between shapekeys, you can create a comparable result using [drivers](https://www.blender.org/manual/animation/drivers/introduction.html). A single control can be made that can enable a series of shapekeys one after the other.